# How can I search a column in MySQL containing unix timestamps?

Tags: mysql, mysql-date

I have mysql table called `user_log` that contains something like:

```
userid  created_at

1       1388514600 
2       1391193000
```

I want to get the record using exact date. For example I have the `created_at` which is `2013-12-31`

```
SELECT * FROM user_log WHERE created_at = UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-31-12');
```

But record is not selected, I don't know what was the problem in that query. So how can I get the record from unix timestamp column in mysql using date?

Comment: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-12-31')` will work a lot better but still not match as it is `1388448000`, not `1388514600`

Comment: 1388514600 this contain timestamp but i'm using date only not datetime

Comment: So given what you now know, update your question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know the exact value in dateformat, you can do :

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at) FROM user_log;
```

That said, the value `1388514600` is not just `2013-12-31` but it's actually `2013-12-31 18:30:00`;

So to search by just date, you can try this:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(created_at) AS dt 
FROM user_log 
HAVING date(dt)='2013-12-31';
```

[Fiddle here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2XPF9Xgg2EkAMM63nDXwBH/1)